# Como protejer los sitios web de mi VPS

Tags: vps

tengo una consulta genera, y basicamente es como protejer lo sitios web en mi vps
basciamente tengo un vps donde instalo un gestor de sitios y aqui los clientes suelen instalar aplicaciones php como wordpress, etc.

la cuestion es que siempre sufren ataques, donde entran a sus sitios (en el caso de wordpress), generan publicaciones aleatorias, agregan una redireccion a otra web, generan archivos .php que al parecer generan mucho trafico en el servidor, aveces logran crear cromjob, etc...

e usando cpanel de pago y otros gestores web gratis.
y en todos ocurre lo mismo, normalmente tengo 3 proveedores, y en todos ocurre esto (unos de muy alta calidad y otros no tanto)

claramente configuro todo lo que amerita, firewall, bloqueos de ip, antivirus.
en el caso de los sitios wordpress, los limpio, les instalo plugins de seguridad y nada...

en fin  no e logrado blindar los vps ya que siempre logran de alguna manera entrar al sitio wordpress o a la cuenta del sitio (por ejemplo cuando no es wordpress y es una aplicacion php creada por el cliente aveces an llegado a corromper esta y agregar codigo malicioso)

mi pregunta es, como resuelvo esto, e mirado cursos de pago, pero todos hablan de firewall, antivirus, reglas, etc, que al final implemento pero no sirve.

estoy atento, gracias

Comment: Y esas apps son seguras? estas seguro que no tienen ningun punto de fuga? ningun lugar expuesto? los WP no tienen claves basicas? tienen el login protegido? Hay mil cosas para mirar... revisaste tus logs a ver donde estaban las entradas? tus firewall bloquean automaticamente ataques?

Comment: Si, bloquean automaticamente intentos de login fallidos, e bloqueado los paises que no me interesan dejando solo el mio activo, y aun asi sigue ocurriendo, me desconcerto algo por ejemplo, cree una cuenta de cpanel para una aplicacion que personalmente prepare y en varias semanas vi que tenia codigo malicioso, pasa mucho en aplicaciones .php, si tienen documentacion de como blindar todo esto les agradezco

Comment: No se brinda documentacion en este sitio, se da ayuda a problemas concretos.. esto no lo parece... No sera que tu servidor entonces ya esta comprometido?

Comment: Como comenta @gbianchi, me suena a que es tu servidor VPS el comprometido.

Comment: Vale, comprendo lo que indican, comprometido seria que lograron acceder a la totalidad del vps, cuando el usuario root tiene claves superior a 30 caracteres, le aplico el lector rootkit  y indica que todo esta en orden, es algo desconcertante por los niveles de seguridad que tiene, les pregunto, un vps se puede comprometer si alguien hackea una web de wordpress ? teniendo WHM ? y claro, tengo 3 vps y todos estan comprometidos ya que en todos pasa lo mismo